# Get focused input class or id in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

Hello I want to retrive the class of the focused Input. For example I have this code:

```
<div class="form-all">
<ul class="form-section">
  <li class="form-line" id="id_8">
    <label class="form-label-left" id="label_8" for="input_8">  </label>
    <div id="cid_8" class="form-input">
      <input type="text" class="form-textbox" id="input_8" name="q8_8" size="50" placeholder="Full Name">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="form-line" id="id_7">
    <label class="form-label-left" id="label_7" for="input_7">  </label>
    <div id="cid_7" class="form-input">
      <input type="text" class="form-textbox" id="input_7" name="q7_7" size="50" placeholder="Company Name">
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class="form-line" id="id_4">
    <label class="form-label-left" id="label_4" for="input_4">  </label>
    <div id="cid_4" class="form-input">
      <input type="email" class="form-textbox validate[Email]" id="input_4" name="q4_4" size="50" placeholder="Email Address">          
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
 </div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This is a form with 23 inputs. I want when I focus an input to add a class to the `<li>`   in witch is the input. I know how to add the class to the `li`, the problem is how to find the input focused....   `$("#input_"+ var).parent().addClass("field-active");`

What is the `var` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try ***[`:focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/)*** selector:

```
$('input:focus').attr('id');
```

to access `class`:

```
$('input:focus').attr('class');
```

you can change the selector if necessary.

#### Check this

```
$('input').on('focus', function() {
    $('.field-active').removeClass('field-active')
    $(this).parent().addClass("field-active");
}).on('blur',function() {
    $('.field-active').removeClass('field-active')
});​
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4exM3/5/)***

Comment: it does not work or I don't know how to use it ... I tried  $("#input:focus").parent().parent().addClass("form-line-active"); .. nada....

Comment: @user1615346 - `input` isn't a valid id.

Comment: @user1615346 check the Demo.. do you want something like that